# Fortran subroutine fails on return

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I have a Fortran numerical code that calls a subroutine from an external module.  This code has been running fine for me until I tried to compile and run on a different machine.  On the new machine, my program crashes fairly quickly.

Using debug print statements, I have isolated that the crash occurs on return from the external subroutine.  The main program calls the subroutine several times, and the crash occurs on return from the second call to the subroutine (the first call works fine).  It always crashes on the second subroutine call with this set of input data, but with another set of input data (roughly 1/3 the size of the first), it crashes on return from the fifth subroutine call.

The symptoms suggest to me that something is getting stored in memory each time and accumulates over each subroutine call until it runs out of space, but I'm not sure what that is or how that would occur.  The code is hard to simplify to a minimal working example, but I have posted the relevant portion below.  Let me know if there is something else that would be helpful to see.  It is basically fixed form Fortran 90.

```
         use fd

         implicit none

         integer, parameter :: ms = 2000
         integer n
         real(dp), dimension(ms) :: s
         real(dp), dimension(ms) :: e
         real(dp), dimension(ms) :: f
         real(dp), dimension(ms) :: d1f
         real(dp), dimension(ms) :: d2f
         real(dp), dimension(ms) :: c, d
         real(dp), dimension(ms) :: a
         real(dp), dimension(ms) :: b
         real(dp), dimension(ms) :: temp
         integer w
         integer k
         real(dp) th

         do i = 1,n
           temp(i) = a(i)
         end do
         call lprsmf(s(1:n),temp(1:n),n,w,k,th,a(1:n),d1f(1:n),
      *               d2f(1:n))

         do i = 1,n
           temp(i) = b(i)
         end do
         call lprsmf(s(1:n),temp(1:n),n,w,k,th,b(1:n),d1f(1:n),
      *               d2f(1:n))

         do i = 1,n
           temp(i) = c(i)
         end do
         call lprsmf(s(1:n),temp(1:n),n,w,k,th,c(1:n),d1f(1:n),
      *               d2f(1:n))

         do i = 1,n
           temp(i) = d(i)
         end do
         call lprsmf(s(1:n),temp(1:n),n,w,k,th,d(1:n),d1f(1:n),
      *               d2f(1:n))

         do i = 1,n
           temp(i) = e(i)
         end do
         call lprsmf(s(1:n),temp(1:n),n,w,k,th,e(1:n),d1f(1:n),
      *               d2f(1:n))

         do i = 1,n
           temp(i) = f(i)
         end do
         call lprsmf(s(1:n),temp(1:n),n,w,k,th,f(1:n),d1f(1:n),
      *               d2f(1:n))
```

module `fd`:

```
      module fd
        ! Double precision real kind
        integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15)

      contains

      subroutine lprsmf(x,y,n,w,k,th,s,d1,d2)
!       INPUTS:
!         x, y, n, w, k, th
!       OUTPUTS:
!         s, d1, d2

        implicit none

        real(dp), dimension(n) :: x,y,s,d1,d2
        integer n,w,k
        real(dp) th

!     ... code here ...

      end subroutine lprsmf

      end module fd
```

My compiler is gfortran 4.6.1.  Besides getting the code to stop crashing, I really would like to understand what is fundamentally going on with the argument passing (as I assume the problem lies with the array slices being passed out of the program).  Note that `a,b,c,d,e,f,s,temp,d1f,d2f` have length 2000, while `n`, which represents the range of valid data, is in the range 100-500, depending on the input data length.

**EDIT:**  The error message is Windows putting up a dialog informing me that the program has stopped working.

Comment: My first thought is to be absolutely certain that the reals you are passing to the routine are indeed double precision, as the routine calls for.  More precisely, make sure of what byte size the routine wants to see in its dp arguments (probably 8, _but not necessarily_) and make sure that is the same as the byte size of the real arguments being passed.  Different compilers handle the precision of real numbers differently.

Comment: @bob.sacamento, I'm pretty sure they're the same, but is there an intrinsic function to check byte size?

Comment: When I want this kind of info, I usually read the compiler documentation, but you can get this info from the "KIND" Fortran intrinsic.  If "r" is a real*8, kind(r) will return 8.  Alternatively, you can be double sure by editing the code so that the size of reals are absolutely specified, i.e. instead of "real", declare with "real(kind=4)" and instead of "double precision", declare with "real(kind=8)".

Comment: @bob.sacamento, The actual arguments are declared the same way as the dummy arguments, if that's what you mean.  I import the constant `dp` from the module into the main program and use it to define the real types there as well.

Comment: OK, if you're sure that all the declarations are 100% consistent, precision isn't the problem.  One other thing I can think of is a segmentation fault.  Alot of the time, the point of failure will have nothing to do with where the bug in the code actually lies.  The two most common causes of seq faults that I have found are writing beyond the bounds of an array and -- not to sound like a broken record -- mismatch between an input parameter list and the types of input variables a subroutine expects.  You can track down the former by compiling with array bounds checking.

Comment: One other thought: see what happens if you compile with no compiler optimization.  If that works, then you have a code somewhere doing something questionable.

Comment: @bob.sacamento, the code still crashes with no compiler optimization.  Also, checking array bounds doesn't turn anything up.  Since the code does run on another machine (and produces meaningful results) with largely the same compiler configuration (different system specs), I don't feel like it's an issue with mismatched arguments or array out-of-bounds.

Comment: Show all declarations in the calling scope for the variables that are being passed.

Comment: Sorry, astay13.  My chambers are empty.  If I think of anything else, I'll let you know.

Comment: You are "use"ing the module that contains subroutine lprsmf from the program that calls it?  Try maximum debugging options with gfortran, such as: -O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fwhole-file  -fcheck=all   -fbacktrace

Comment: Hi, could you update your question with the actual error message you get when the program crashes, is it a segfault? The first thing I would definitely do is follow M.S.B.'s advice, or at least use '-fcheck=bounds' (using gfortran).

Comment: @steabert, I have added details on the error, basically, it's just Windows putting up the dialog telling me the program stopped working.  I'm not sure if that means segfault or something else.

Comment: @astay13 Where is `n` set in your program? Also, just a note on style, can you not replace `do i = 1,n` `temp(i) = d(i)` `end do` with just `temp(1:n) = d(1:n)`?

Comment: @Chris, The program is reading a data file with an unknown number of lines.  It reads lines until EOF, incrementing `n` each time.  At the end of reading input, `n` represents the number of valid items in each array.  Regarding `do ... end do` vs. `temp(1:n) = d(1:n)`, I was trying to make a deep copy of `d` into `temp`.  I wasn't sure that `temp(1:n) = d(1:n)` would do that.  I'm still a little fuzzy on referencing in Fortran though, so I'm definitely open to better ways of doing things.

Comment: With regards to the do loop, AFAIK they are equivalent. My point concerning the value of `n` is that you haven't given us a [short, self-contained code example](sscce.org/), which makes it very hard for us to track down what is going on. Can you update your question with a minimal *complete* program which reproduces your error?

Comment: Anyway, one obvious source of error will be when n > 2000 (or `ms`). You have no error checking for this case.

Comment: @Chris, I do realize how hard it is to provide useful assistance without a complete program that reproduces the error.  The program is complex enough that it's not very easy to come up with an SSCCE that replicates the error, so I had been hoping to avoid doing so.  I will start working on one though.

Comment: without much more details, it's difficult. What I don't get is that you don't seem to initialize the value of n anywhere, is that just a typo?

Comment: @astay13, Chris is right about the `do ... end do' vs. 'temp(1:n) = d(1:n)`.  They are completely equivalent.  That should make your code more compact, even if it won't solve the problem.  Speaking of which, I'm also with Chris in that you need to be absolutely certain that n is never greater than ms.

Comment: And I am grasping at straws here, but here's a thought: In all your calls to lprsmf, you do not need to specify the indices of your arrays, i.e. "s" will work instead of "s(1:n)", since you are starting with s(1) anyway.  In fact, specfying the indices is a little unusual.  I am really grasping at straws here, but I would get rid of those indices and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for the help in chasing down this problem.  I followed [M.S.B.'s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764960/fortran-subroutine-fails-on-return#comment15630980_11764960) and compiled with `-O2 -fimplicit-none -Wall -Wline-truncation -Wcharacter-truncation -Wsurprising -Waliasing -Wimplicit-interface -Wunused-parameter -fwhole-file -fcheck=all -fbacktrace`.  This revealed a memory leak in someone else's older F77 code I had included in my subroutine.  Apparently some internal arrays were declared with a length 1 item shorter than needed.  I fixed that, and everything seems to work fine now.